# Array Pagination - Writing Equation

Tags: php, oop

Am working on array pagination. I am having some trouble forming equations. what I want is when `$CurrentPage = 1` then `$Start = 1`, if `$CurrentPage = 2` then `$Start = 6`, if `$CurrentPage = 3` then `$Start = 11`, if `$CurrentPage = 4` then`$Start = 16` and so on..

How do I write the `if else` block ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about simply

```
$Start = $CurrentPage * 5 - 4;
```

Comment: Cant believe how simple it was and how dumb I am!! :) Thank you so much @Borodin

Comment: @confused_developer: Seeing these things comes with practice. I suggest you change your SO tag, otherwise it will haunt you when you become the best of the best.

Comment: Sorry for another dumb question - but what's SO tag?

Comment: *Stack Overflow* tag. You have called yourself *confused_developer* and that is like naming a baby *Cherub Rosebud*: he won't thank you when he's a strapping 20-year-old!

Answer (score 2):

You can write

```
$Start = ($CurrentPage - 1) * 5 + 1;
```

No `if else` block needed at all, which makes your code indepent to the minimum or maximum number of pages. You can also change the magic number `5` as the number of entries per page later on easily.

Comment: Yes @hakre you're right, no `if else` block required. And that magic number 5 is actually `$RowsPerPage`, just wanted to keep it simple. And thank you so much

Comment: You also wrote it's array pagination, see the nice  [`array_chunk`](http://php.net/array_chunk) function as well, it's well suited for pagination. Another helpful thingy is the [`LimitIterator`](http://php.net/LimitIterator).

Answer (score 1):

What you want is

```
$firstItem = ($pageNumber - 1) * $pageSize;
```

This would be a zero-based index. Add one if you want it to be one-based.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need if else block, just math :

```
$Start = ($CurrentPage-1)*5+1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are making pagination with page size, right? If that, so there s my soluton:

```
$pageSize = 5;
$start = ($currentPage - 1) * $pageSize + 1;
```

Why $start need to be 1? Because arrays in PHP start from index 0. So I think you should do:

```
$start = ($currentPage - 1) * $pageSize;
```